# IntelliJ Idea Ultimate 2023.2.5 does not support Angular 17 new control flow

Tags: angular, intellij-idea

I have recently updated an Angular project to 17, and just see, that in HTML templates the new syntax is not recognized in Idea.

```
      <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
        @for (menuItem of getData().menu.items; track menuItem) {
          <button mat-menu-item (click)="onMenuClick(menuItem)">
            <mat-icon>{{menuItem.icon}}</mat-icon>
            <span>{{menuItem.label}}</span>
          </button>
        }
      </mat-menu>
```

It says: Unterminated expansion form. If you have unescaped '{', use '{{ "{" }}' to escape it. And also code formatting does not work as expected.

I have checked if there is a refreshed version of Idea, but I am already on the newest one. I use the Linux version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is support for Angular 17 in the newest beta build of the *Angular and AngularJS* plugin. The beta version of Intelij Idea (2023.3) with that version of plugin was released a couple of days ago.

So either get Intelij Idea 2023.3 Beta version or try to install the newest *Angular and AngularJS* plugin build.

Comment: Works fine in 2023.3 Beta! Thank you!